# Are there any Windows equivalents to Apple's Mission Control

Tags: windows, window-manager, mission-control

I'm trying to find something for Windows 7 that simplifies working with multiple programs & files the same way that Mission Control does for the Mac. I frequently have 5 or 6 programs running and often 3+ instances of those. Even with 3 monitors, it's difficult to organize everything so that I can see, at a glance, everything that I'm currently working on.

I don't expect there to be something out there that's exactly like Apple's Mission Control, but am looking for something that can simplify the desktop experience.

Comment: Have you tried Alt+Tab or WindowKey+Tab?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one ...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcsoft/

It arranges thumbnails into "piles" like mission control does, but with even a little more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

[Switcher](http://insentient.net/) seems like expose, i know that is not mission control but its better than the normal alt+tab :-D

hope it works!

Comment: Tried switcher. Doesn't look too bad. Unfortunately, it requires Aero to be turned on and Aero is incompatible with the the USB-VGA converters that I'm using for monitors 2 & 3.

Comment: Switcher works well, but it is not what's being asked. I use SmallWindow.

Answer (score 1):

[Emcee](http://emceesoftware.net/) has expose/mission control features. It is a commercial product but it has a two-week free trial. It has a settings editor, installer, hot-key and hot-corner customization, and many other features. Under Windows 8, it incorporates support for both Modern and desktop applications.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this before http://smallwindows.sourceforge.net/

It works very well, however, I installed it and couldn't find myself using it.

Comment: Works well.  My only complaint is that it does not show minimized windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best functionality I've found. It might be more like spaces, but it's super customizable and allows up to 20 screens!

http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=download

Answer (score 0):

**BetterDesktopTool** (sometimes written as “Better Desktop Tool”) brings desktop customization functionality like Exposé and Spaces (aka Mission Control post OSX 10.7) to Windows. The app makes it much more efficient to locate and select windows. It displays all the windows in an overview without overlapping them. The application comes with a Virtual-Desktops feature, which allows you to extend your workspace.

Download:

http://download.cnet.com/BetterDesktopTool/3000-2346_4-75812098.html

Alternatively:

**Preme For Windows** - **An application for speeding up your switching windows.**

**Features:**

- Functional Screen Corner - It serves you many functions at the screen corners. You can select
- Touch Start - Start menu will show automatically, and then hide immediately when your pointer is not on start menu.
- Hide Active - Your active window will be disappeared temporarily, so you can see some detail behind the active window.
- Switcher (Aero Flip 3D)
- Switcher (Task Switcher)

To name but a few.

More info:

http://www.premeforwindows.com/